# Achieving local `@fptop` within a custom float

Tags: spacing, floats, positioning

I would like the following policy:

- The top of `figure` and `table` page-floats should be 15% down the page (and ideally able to move higher if the figure is more than 85% of text height).
- A custom environment (`smallbox`) should be vertically centred

Essentially, I want to set `@fptop` to `0.15\textheight minus 0.15\textheight` except for the `mybox` case (where the default `@fptop` should apply).

My initial solution was to set:

```
\setlength{\@fptop}{0.15\textheight minus 0.15\textheight}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
```

and then with the following environment:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}  %% 
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={List of boxes}, name = {Box}]{boxe}
% The smallbox is a box intended for onecolumn.
\newenvironment{smallbox}[3][p]{%
  \begin{boxe}[#1]
  }{\end{boxe}}
```

adding a large space (such as `\vspace*{\fill}` in the last argument of the environment. However, this does nothing (*i.e.* keeps the top of the `smallbox` at 15% of textheight) or moves it too far (i.e. the smallbox is at the top of the page).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}  %% twocolumn makes fptop more obvious
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0.15\textheight minus 0.15\textheight}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={List of boxes}, name = {Box}]{boxe}
\newenvironment{smallbox}[1][p]{%
\begin{boxe}[#1]
}{\end{boxe}} 

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
.

\begin{figure}[p]
\caption{foo}
\includegraphics{}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
.

\begin{smallbox}
\lipsum[1]
\end{smallbox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: In other words, you would like to set `\@fptop` an a per-float-type basis, wouldn’t you?  I’m afraid this is impossible, unless you change LaTeX’s output routine.  Also note that floats are not unboxed when thet are delivered to their destination.

Comment: But, on the other hand, the very concept of a “local \@fptop” is meaningless: indeed, floats of more than one type can quite well end up on the same page; what would you want to do in that case?

Comment: I agree the concept is meaningless -- I was just expressing it like that as a (poor) description. I am happy for a solution which makes a page with a  `smallbox` unable to hold any other floats on the page.

Comment: Then, you have already posted *the* solution (which I’m going to upvote! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that using a `minipage` appears to work a few hours after posting.

```
\newenvironment{smallbox}[1][p]{%
\begin{boxe}[#1]
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\linewidth}
}{\end{minipage}\end{boxe}}
```